# How to load a json from externally to a D3 application

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a D3 application where I have a structure that shows a relationship between nodes. I need exactly this application for my purpose. But the problem is that the application is using a hardcode json like structure in its html page, which does not fit my purpose.I need to load the json externally from a .json file. Here i have tried to make the json from that hardcodes portion, and also tried to write some code that will load the json externally but it is not working .here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.link {
fill: none;
stroke: #666;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#licensing {
fill: green;
}

.link.licensing {
stroke: green;
 }

.link.resolved {
stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
 }

 circle {
fill: #ccc;
stroke: #333;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
font: 10px sans-serif;
pointer-events: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
 }
 </style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/

    /*Here licensing type is making the green arrow
     *Here resolved type is making the solid arrow
     *Here suit type is making the dotted arrow
     *
     *
     **/

     var links = [];

     d3.json("directed.json", function(error, json) {

         links = json.links.forEach(function(d){
         d.source=json.nodes[d.source];
         t.target=json.nodes[d.target];



               });


     });
    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
            name : link.source
        });
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
            name : link.target
        });
    });

    var width = 960, height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(d3.values(nodes)).links(links)
            .size([ width, height ]).linkDistance(60).charge(-300).on(
                    "tick", tick).start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
            "height", height);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker").data(
            [ "suit", "licensing", "resolved" ]).enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d;
            }).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10").attr("refX", 15).attr("refY",
                    -1.5).attr("markerWidth", 6).attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto").append("path").attr("d",
                    "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path").data(force.links())
            .enter().append("path").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "link " + d.type;
            }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
            });

    var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("circle").attr("r", 6).call(force.drag);

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("text").attr("x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });

    //selection is happening 
    var selected = circle.filter(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

    selected.each(function(d) {
        // d contains the data for the node and this is the circle element

        console.log(d.name);
    });

    var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("circle").attr("r", 6).on("click", clickfn)
            .call(force.drag);

    var clickfn = function(node) {
        alert(node);
    }

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
        path.attr("d", linkArc);
        circle.attr("transform", transform);
        text.attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, dy = d.target.y - d.source.y, dr = Math
                .sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr
                + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
</script>
```

i have made the json

```
       {
            "links" : [ {
            "source" : "Microsoft",
            "target" : "Amazon",
            "type" : "licensing"
        }, {
            "source" : "Microsoft",
            "target" : "HTC",
            "type"   : "licensing"
        }, {
            "source" : "Samsung",
            "target" : "Apple",
            "type"  : "suit"
        }, {
            "source" : "Motorola",
            "target" : "Apple",
            "type"   :  "suit"
        }, {
            "source": "Nokia",
            "target": "Apple",
            "type"  : "resolved"
        }, {
            "source": "HTC",
            "target": "Apple",
            "type"  : "suit"
        }, {
            "source" : "Kodak",
            "target" : "Apple",
            "type" : "suit"
        }, {
            "source": "Microsoft",
            "target": "Barnes & Noble",
            "type" :"suit"
        }, {
            "source": "Microsoft",
            "target": "Foxconn",
            "type" :"suit"
        }, {
            "source": "Apple",
            "target": "HTC",
            "type" :"suit"
        }, {
            "source" : "Microsoft",
            "target" : "Inventec",
            "type" : "suit"
        }, {
            "source" : "Samsung",
            "target" : "Kodak",
            "type" : "resolved"
        }, {
            "source" : "LG",
            "target" : "Kodak",
            "type" : "resolved"
        }, {
            "source": "RIM",
            "target": "Kodak",
            "type" :"suit"
        }, {
            "source" : "Sony",
            "target" : "LG",
            "type" : "suit"
        }, {
            "source" : "Kodak",
            "target" : "LG",
            "type" : "resolved"
        }, {
            "source" : "Apple",
            "target" : "Nokia",
            "type" : "resolved"
        }, {
            "source": "Qualcomm",
            "target": "Nokia",
            "type" :"resolved"
        }, {
            "source" : "Kodak",
            "target" : "Samsung",
            "type" : "resolved"
        }, {
           "source" : "Apple",
           "target" : "Samsung",
           "type" : "suit"
        }, {
            "source": "Kodak",
            "target": "RIM",
            "type" :"licensing"
        }, {
            "source": "Kodak",
            "target": "Qualcomm",
            "type" :"licensing"
        } ]
     }
```

and i have modified my code with this

```
var nodes = {};
     d3.json("directed.json", function(error, graph) {

        graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
        d.source = graph.nodes[d.source];
        d.target = graph.nodes[d.target];
  });
```

but nothing is coming to the screen .will anybody help me???

Comment: can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you tell me the error you getting in console???

Comment: @sam  [13:04:19.901] TypeError: links.nodes is undefined @ http://localhost:8080/D3JsonApp/mulselect.jsp:52

Comment: @sam have you got anything sam ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  d3.json(
                    "directed.json",
                    function(error, directed) {

                         links=directed.links;


                        links.forEach(function(link) {
                            link.source = nodes[link.source]
                                    || (nodes[link.source] = {
                                        name : link.source
                                    });
                            link.target = nodes[link.target]
                                    || (nodes[link.target] = {
                                        name : link.target
                                    });
                        });
```

try this this is working for me .....

Answer (score 0):

According with your 1st code and the JSON the XHR call must to be

```
var links = [];

d3.json("directed.json", function(error, json) {
          links = json.links;
}).on("load", function () {

// rest of the code here

});
```

Comment: i have updated the code here but not working can you see please?

Comment: [12:26:08.211] TypeError: links.forEach(...) is undefined  this is the errr i am gettig

Comment: put a console.log(error,json,links) to see what happends.
Your approach isn't the best to use D3js try to use d3.selectAll(), d3.json() and selection.data().
I will try to make a bl.oks later with this.

Comment: i am using the code i have edited and also the error  i am getting in the console will you please see?

Comment: i am getting links.nodes is undefined